# how to print last incremented value in set_fact ansible?

Tags: variables, ansible, increment, ansible-facts

Here is my ansible playbook. I'm inputting a file to my playbook and if it finds keywords like `"open"` or `"allowed"` in the file, I'm asking it to increment the variable `dbsuccesscount` by 1.

```yaml
 - name: testing
    set_fact: dbsuccescount={{ dbsuccescount | int + 1 }}
    when: item | regex_search('OPEN') and item | regex_search('ALLOWED')
    with_items: "{{ file_check.stdout_lines }}"
    tags: dbstatus_success
 - debug:
     var: dbsuccescount
```

Increment works successfully like below (last success number is 107).
snippet of the output

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=OPEN,ALLOWED) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "dbsuccescount": "107"
    }, 
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": "OPEN,ALLOWED"
```

However I would like to print this last value which is 107 from `dbsuccesscount`. How can we print/read it?

I tried running the below which doesn't work

debug: msg="{{ dbsuccescount }} | last "

expected result:

I want my output to look like below

the dbsucesscount is 107 --> which is the last incremented value

Comment: What do you mean by, "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message (what is it)? Are you seeing unexpected behavior?

Comment: so my dbsuccesscount is not just a single value. it increments and finally reaches to 107. when i run the debug command , it simply doesn't print any output.
 my logic might be missing something, can you recommend a way on how we can pull last value of the incremented fact ?

Comment: It seems to work when I run it: the `debug` task prints out the value of `dbsuccescount`, which reflects the number of lines matched in the previous step.

Comment: how can we print only the last value of dbsuccesscount instead of printing the entire list ?

Comment: Rather than `it doesn't work` and/or a vague literate description of what your get. provide a [mre] in wich you show what you exactly get and what you exactly expect instead. Please don't provide this in comments: [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is correct as written. Here's a complete example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    file_check:
      stdout_lines:
        - OPEN ALLOWED
        - junk
        - junk
        - OPEN ALLOWED
        - junk
        - OPEN ALLOWED
  tasks:
   - name: testing
     set_fact:
       dbsuccesscount: "{{ dbsuccesscount | default(0) | int + 1 }}"
     when: item | regex_search('OPEN') and item | regex_search('ALLOWED')
     with_items: "{{ file_check.stdout_lines }}"
     tags: dbstatus_success

   - debug:
       var: dbsuccesscount
```

Running this produces:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [testing] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=OPEN ALLOWED)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=junk) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=junk) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=OPEN ALLOWED)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=junk) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=OPEN ALLOWED)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dbsuccesscount": "3"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

There are three matching lines, so the `debug` task is printing exactly what we expect.

---

Of course, you don't need a `with_items` loop to count the number of matching lines; you can use a filter instead:

```
   - name: testing
     set_fact:
       dbsuccescount: "{{ file_check.stdout_lines | select('match', 'OPEN|ALLOWED') | length }}"

   - debug:
       var: dbsuccescount
```

This produces the same output.